# Plotting any number of images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text

I want to plot random number of images. Means i have searched images related to my query, the images can be 5,6 or more based on the query given. Is there any way to plot them automatically based on the number of images matched.

Here is my code so far:

```
for k = 1:length(textfiles) 
    file = [sdirectory '/' textfiles(k).name]; 
    file1 = [sdirectory1 '/' imgfiles(k).name]; 
    fid=fopen(file,'r'); 
    tline = fgetl(fid); 

    while ischar(tline) 
         line_string = sprintf('%s',tline); 
         x = get(handles.edit1,'String'); 
         u=strfind(line_string,x); 
         tline = fgetl(fid); 

         if u>0 
              file2=imread(file1); 
              figure,imshow(imresize(file2,0.5)),title(file1); 
              break; 
         end 
    end 
    fclose(fid); 
end
```

Comment: `for k = 1:length(textfiles)`
`file = [sdirectory '/' textfiles(k).name];`
`file1 = [sdirectory1 '/' imgfiles(k).name];`
`fid=fopen(file,'r');`
`tline = fgetl(fid);`
`while ischar(tline)`
`    line_string = sprintf('%s',tline);`
    `x = get(handles.edit1,'String');`
   ` u=strfind(line_string,x);`
    `tline = fgetl(fid);`
    `if u>0`
        `file2=imread(file1);`
        `figure,imshow(imresize(file2,0.5)),title(file1);`
        `break;`
`end`
`end`
`fclose(fid);`
`end `

Comment: in above code final images are in file1

Comment: I pasted your code directly in your question. Now, can you describe what the output of this is, and what you would like instead?

Comment: in this code images matching to query string are retrieved. The image can be any number based on the string you enter. The images are stored in the variable `file1`. I would like the images to be plotted into a single figure knowing that number of images can be different as per the given query.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate them into a multiframe/multipage image (4D matrix), and display them with `montage`.

```
mframe = cat (4, img1, img2, img3);
montage (mframe)
```

Since you don't know the number of images to plot, you can throw them all into a cell array first:

```
mframe = cell (); % if you know in advance the number of images...
for ...
  ## whatever code you have to pick the right images
  mframe{end+1} = img;
endfor
mframe = cat (4, mframe{:});
montage (mframe)
```

This assumes that images are all of the same size, all RGB or grayscale, and same class, If they are not, you can pad them easily with `padarray`, and convert them to the same class with `im2uint8`, `im2double`, etc...

Comment: gives undefined function or variable `mframe`

Comment: That is an impressive guesswork of OP's original question. I only understood it looking at his code.

Comment: @user3416063 I'm guessing you tried to use the for loop. You must initialize an empty cell array before the loop (I have just adjusted the question).